# Android Custom view Dialog Dismiss

Tags: android

1. List item

Help Please!!  I am creating 1 simple game. 
For that, I have created one custom view.

```
public class GameView extends View
```

I have a button which opens settings of the game. So I have created a Dialog box for that.
After dialog button pressed I re-draw in my custom view.   But it's not immediately refreshing view. It takes few seconds.

```
enter code here
public void settingFunction()
{
    int musicOn=-1; int suitLevel = -1;
    final Dialog endDialog = new Dialog(mycontext);
    endDialog.setCancelable(false);
    endDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    endDialog.setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    TextView settingText = (TextView) endDialog.findViewById(R.id.textLayout);
    TextView settingText1 = (TextView) endDialog.findViewById(R.id.textLayout_1);
    Button nextButton = (Button) endDialog.findViewById(R.id.nextHandButton);
    final Switch sw1 = (Switch) endDialog.findViewById(R.id.switch1);

    RadioButton easy = (RadioButton) endDialog.findViewById(R.id.easy);
    RadioButton medium = (RadioButton) endDialog.findViewById(R.id.medium);
    RadioButton hard = (RadioButton) endDialog.findViewById(R.id.difficult);
    //dbC.insertSetting("MUSIC",1);
    String st = "MUSIC";
    musicOn =dbC.readSetting( st);
    suitLevel =dbC.readSetting( "SUIT");
     int ct ;
    //sw1.setChecked(true);
    //Toast.makeText(mycontext," music" + musicOn ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(musicOn ==1)
    {
        sw1.setChecked(true);
    } else {sw1.setChecked(false);}

    if(suitLevel ==1)
    {
        easy.setChecked(true);
    } else if (suitLevel ==2)
    {medium.setChecked(true);} else if (suitLevel==3) {easy.setChecked(true);}

    endDialog.show();

    sw1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
            new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                {
                    if(isChecked)
                    {dbC.updateSetting("MUSIC",1);
                    }
                    else {dbC.updateSetting("MUSIC",0);}
                }
            }
    );
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            initalAnimation = 1;
            endDialog.dismiss();
            invalidate();
            //alertUser();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code sample.

Comment: whitout code we can't help

Comment: I have added the code.  nextButton.setOnClickListener is the code I am concerned.

Comment: @Nitin please check your `onDraw()` code. are you doing any heavy operation there?

Comment: yes. I am ding some animation. When I am debugging , I can see that code first goes to View.Java then LOOPER.JAVA

Comment: @Nitin if you're initializing some object try to avoid it.